# Filter Wordpress Comments via user role

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am creating a website using WordPress that has two user types: 1. General 2. Expert. I have restricted my posts so that only logged-in users can comment on it. What i want to do is to filter out the comments left by these users separately. The filter needs to be applied on user role. Can somebody please tell me how to do that?
Right now, i am trying to get it from this code `get_comments()`

```
<?php $args = array(
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'meta_query' => '',
);
get_comments( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Milaps solution is very good and detailed. that's a more quick and dirty solution (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
    $users = get_users(array('role' => 'General'));
    $userids = array();
    foreach($users as $user){
        $userids[] = $user->ID;
    }
    $args = array(
        'author__in' => $userids
    );
    get_comments( $args );
```

you can use the authorids (which are the userids) and retrieve comments by them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple plugin as below :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Comment Roles
Description: Allows filering of comments by user role.
Version: 0.0.1
Author: Kendall Weaver
Author URI: http://kendallweaver.com
License: GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

function comment_roles_form() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $roles = $wp_roles->roles;

    echo '<form method="get">';

    foreach($roles as $key => $value) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="comment-role[]" value="' . $key . '" />' . $value['name'] . '<br />';
    }

    echo '<input type="submit" value="Filter">';
    echo '</form>';
}
add_action( 'comments_template', 'comment_roles_form' );

function comment_roles_filter($comments) {
    $roles = $_GET["comment-role"];

    if ($roles != NULL) {
        $users = array();

        foreach($roles as $role) {
            $userlist = get_users('role=' . $role);

            foreach($userlist as $user) {
                $users[] = $user->ID;
            }
        }

        foreach($comments as $comment => $data) {
            if (!in_array($data->user_id, $users)) {
                unset( $comments[$comment]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $comments;
}
add_filter( 'comments_array', 'comment_roles_filter' );
```

Alternative plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-roles/

Reference : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-comments-by-user-role